# user input doesn't get processed

Tags: ruby, user-input, tic-tac-toe

I am a newbie and really stuck with this problem. 
I need the array element that matches the user input to be replaced with "X". What am I doing wrong? Can you please help!? Thanks!

```
class Round 

  def start 
    display_board
    pick
    refresh_board
  end

  #displays the board in the begining of the game
  def display_board
    @board = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
    @board.each do |i|
      puts i.join("|")
    end
  end

  def refresh_board
    @changed_board = []
    @board.each do |i|
      if i.include?(@input)
        r = i.index(@input)
        i[r] = "X"
        @changed_board << i
      else
        @changed_board << i
      end
    end

    @changed_board.each do |i|
      puts i.join("|")
    end
  end

 #player selects a number
  def pick
    puts "player1, select a number:"
    @input = gets.chomp
  end
end

round1 = Round.new 
round1.start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `i.include?(@input)` never returns `true` because the array `i` is made of `Integer`, and `@input` is a `String`.

That's what's happening:

```
[1,2,3].include?("1") #=> false
```

To make it work, you can convert `@input` to `Integer` when setting it.

Another thing: as well pointed by @JörgWMittag, you don't need [`String#chomp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp), as `to_i` ignores whitespaces as well.

Just replace this line:

```
@input = gets.chomp
```

with:

```
@input = gets.to_i
```

And it will work!

Comment: `String#to_i` ignores whitespace, no need to `chomp` it.

Comment: @JörgWMittag thanks, I edited the answer with your suggestion